GixSql con Gnucobol prepared statements no funciona
este es el codigo:
WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.

01 SQL-STM   SQL TYPE IS VARCHAR(300).

...

PROCEDURE DIVISION.
 
...

 STRING 
    SQL-TODAS DELIMITED BY SIZE
    SQL-PRIMERO DELIMITED BY SIZE
 INTO SQL-STM.


 EXEC SQL 
    PREPARE SQLSTMT1 FROM :SQL-STM
END-EXEC.

 EXEC SQL
    EXECUTE SQLSTMT1 USING :PERIODO
 END-EXEC.


Retorna eror -1064

El contenido de SQL-STM es:
SELECT  prdo, cdgo_cnta, dscrpcion_cnta, axliar, trcro,cdgo_trcro, bse, ajste, cta_amnto, 
        cta_cntrprtda
  INTO :PERI-CTA, :CODI-CTA, :NOMB-CTA, :AUXI-CTA, :TERC-CTA,:COD3-CTA, :BASE-CTA,
       :AJUI-CTA, :DEBI-AJU, :CRED-AJU 
FROM cntas WHERE prdo = ? ORDER BY cdgo_cnta ASC LIMIT 1

Si se ejecuta esta sentencia en la base de datos funciona correctamente.
Si en el mismo Gnucobol se ejecuta como una sentencia selec normal, funciona correctamente. Hice la prueba con prepared, porque tengo otras consultas, donde si es necesario utilizarlo.
